# Localization of icon and default screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, localization, icons

Can the app icon and default screen be localized in iPhone? Has anyone tried it?

In theory it should be possible as they're just image resources, but I found no explicit mention of this in the documentation, and I wouldn't like to have my app rejected or failing for this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) quote:

"An iPhone application should be internationalized and have a language.lproj  directory for each language it supports. In addition to providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources, you can also localize your application icon (Icon.png), default image (Default.png), and Settings icon (Icon-Settings.png) by placing files with the same name in your language-specific project directories. Even if you provide localized versions, however, you should always include a default version of these files at the top-level of your application bundle. The default version is used in situations where a specific localization is not available."

Comment: Thanks. I was looking in Internationalization Programming Topics.

Comment: I tried it. I can't get it to work. I localized both Icon.png and Icon@2x.png but only one of them show up no matter what (always the Japanese one, not English (I have Jap/Eng localized))

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible anymore, the documentation is misleading and wrong. It can be done since iOS 4.0 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17525881/62921

Answer (score 10):

I'm trying to do the same, and I found this:

Until yesterday though I was never totally sure it was not possible. Then I spotted this thread in the Apple developer forums. There is a post by Bill Dudney, author of the excellent iPhone SDK Development book from Pragmatic Programmers and now an Apple employee. Bill confirms that localizing the application icon is not currently supported and suggests raising an enhancement request.

source: 
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/16/localizing-iphone-app-icon-is-not-supported.html

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Very frustrating and absolutely critical to our sales.  Do you think I will get rejected for releasing 2 apps as long as I restrict regions (i.e they dont overlap?)  So disappointing...

Comment: The question is has anyone actually managed it? I have read so many questions on stackoverflow quoting the documentation but nowhere has anyone said they have done it and nowhere is there an example. It's getting frustrating people answering questions of "can it be done?" without ever showing how it can be done!