# Is it possible to localize the app icon and Default.png?

Tags: iphone, localization, locale

Is it possible to localize the app icon and Default.png files? Do I just drop them in the respective language folders or must I do something else?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700311/localization-of-icon-and-default-screen-in-iphone

Comment: @BoltClock, so vote to close please. I did, once you posted that.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote to close other questions.

Comment: @Ok. Thanks for the comment though. It got me my answer.  I'll upvote you to help the rep. ;)

Comment: Heh, thanks. Except, upvoting my comments doesn't give me rep, sadly, only answers! D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, there's an answer elsewhere, but you can read more in the [*Internationalizing Your Application*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/applicationenvironment/applicationenvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW23) section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide. There's an example of how to structure your language files in your app bundle, for example.

Comment: Sure did, +10 for upvote and +15 for accept. The Stack Overflow FAQ has all you need to know about rep http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I knew that it helped ;) not the numbers though.

Comment: It's not possible to internationalize the app icon.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The correct answer is that it is not possible to localize the app icon.</s>

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a
>   language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to
>   providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources,
>   you **can also localize your application icons and launch images** by
>   placing files with the same name in your language-specific project
>   directories. Even if you provide localized versions, however, you
>   should always include a default version of these files at the
>   top-level of your application bundle. The default version is used in
>   situations where a specific localization is not available. For more
>   information about localized resources, see “Localized Resources in
>   Bundles.”

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

Apple docs update/change frequently. This is the correct link at this point in time. Also, I haven't actually tried localizing the app icon/default images, but Apple says it works so why not :-)

This same question appears numerous times on stackoverflow.

Comment: not sure why this was voted down.  it is the short, correct answer.

Comment: This is short,,  But wrong answer,, Advice:If you do not know the answer, Don't misguide others with wrong answers...

Comment: I researched it again and changed it... :-P