# Is it possible to have 2 different application icons depending on the language?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization of icon and default screen in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700311/localization-of-icon-and-default-screen-in-iphone)

As my question already says, I want to have 2 different application icons.
If for example english is the native language on the device I want it not only to have a different app name but also a different icon.
So is that actually possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to apple documentation, you can do it.

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a
>   language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to
>   providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources,
>   **you can also localize your application icons and launch images by
>   placing files with the same name in your language-specific project
>   directories.** Even if you provide localized versions, however, you
>   should always include a default version of these files at the
>   top-level of your application bundle. The default version is used in
>   situations where a specific localization is not available. For more
>   information about localized resources, see “Localized Resources in
>   Bundles.”

This info was extracted from here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like it that you actually provided the documentation link. I looked through it but didn't find it!

Comment: iOS page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html but contains the same stuff basically

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, if you want too... just click on your icon file (consider **Icon.png**) now simply click on the ‘+’ in that ‘Localization’ pane on the right.

Add languanges that you want to provide support. Consider you have English And Spanish language support, add those two languages. It will create ‘en.lproj’ and ‘es.lproj’.

Now just see those directory, you can see both directories have their own copy of **Icon.png**. So just replace that image and make sure new file has same name as the replaced one.

Now Run it. And check by changing language in **Setting>International>Language**

Basic thing is based on language it will check if localization is available for that particular resource, if it exists it will be used.

Answer (score -2):

<s>No, you can't have localized app icons</s>

Sorry, I was very wrong, it is possible. I was quite sure but my information obviously was very outdated :).

Comment: You are providing false information, according to apple documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I was sure about that! So I learned something new, too :). Sorry again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278633/how-to-localize-an-app-icon says you might be right after all